# Convert NSString 8-8-2015 12:00:00 AM to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am aware that this question is asked too many times but none matched my requirement.

I have "8-8-2015 12:00:00 AM" in `NSString` named strEventTimeBegin. How do I convert this NSString to NSDate? Here's what I tried but returns null.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *startEventDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strEventTimeBegin];
```

Comment: It doesn't work because your date format doesn't come close to matching the format of your string. Everything has to match and be in the same order.

Comment: you might have spotted the number formatter is for a completely different pattern. does this fact not really bother you a bit at least? the `M-d-yyyy hh:mm:ss a` could be much closer to the reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, but this should work:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Just to explain, in your example;

1. The day and the year are backwards.
2. You're using 2 digit days and
   months (It's looking for 08-08-2015).
3. You're missing the period
   (AM/PM) identifier.

Comment: It's 12-hour time, use `hh`, not `HH`.